# Direct way to set fixed column width for existing excel file using pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I was wondering if there's a direct way to set the column width for an already existing excel file using pandas without regenerating the file or altering it in anyway except by changing its column width?

I just want a way to set the column width for a given column to a fixed width in any measurement.

Answer (score 0):

What really worked for me after some time is using openpyxl library version number 3.0.3.

Version 3.0.1 has problems so stay away from it.

I used the following code and it worked wonderfully:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

def format_file(file):
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    print(wb.sheetnames)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = 75
    ws.sheet_properties.tabColor = "1072BA"
    wb.save(filename = "absolute/path/to/your/excel/file")
```